# If $a^2=b^2+c^2$ and $0<n<2$ prove $a^n<b^n+c^n$

Tags: inequality, polynomials

If $a^2=b^2+c^2$ and $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, prove

(a) if $n>2$ then $a^n>b^n+c^n$,

(b) if $0<n<2$ then $a^n<b^n+c^n$.

Part (a) was easy to prove: $a^2=b^2+c^2$ and $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers, so $a>b$ and $a>c$. Then O can show: $b^n+c^n=b^2(b^{n-2})+c^2(c^{n-2})<b^2(a^{n-2})+c^2(a^{n-2})=a^{n-2}(b^2+c^2)=a^{n-2}\times a^2=a^n \implies b^n+c^n<a^n$

But I stuck in part (b). Can I prove it in a way I proved part (a)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you did in (a), we can do as fellows: when $0<n<2$
$$a^n=\frac{a^2}{a^{2-n}}=\frac{b^2}{a^{2-n}}+\frac{c^2}{a^{2-n}}<\frac{b^2}{b^{2-n}}+\frac{c^2}{c^{2-n}}=b^n+c^n.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$a^2+b^2=c^2\iff \left(\frac ac\right)^2=1-\left(\frac bc\right)^2\le1$$

$$\implies\left(\frac ac\right)^n<\left(\frac ac\right)^2$$  for $n>2$

Answer (score 1):

We need to show: $\left(\dfrac{b^2}{a^2}\right)^{x} + \left(\dfrac{c^2}{a^2}\right)^{x} > 1$ for $0< x = \dfrac{n}{2}< 1$, and $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$. Let $u = \dfrac{b^2}{a^2}$, and $v = \dfrac{c^2}{a^2}$, then $0 < u,v < 1$, and $u+v = 1$, and we now prove: $u^x + v^x > 1$.

Consider $f(x) = u^x + v^x$ on $(0,1)$. We have: $f'(x) = u^x\cdot \ln u + v^x\cdot \ln v < 0$ because $\ln u < 0$, and $\ln v < 0$ for $0 < u,v < 1$. Thus $f(x)$ decreases, and $f(x) > f(1) = u+v = 1$.

Comment: thanks for complete answer. but I've not studied natural logarithm yet

Answer (score 0):

These may help you:

First prove for $n = 1$ (Easy, as $a = \sqrt{b^2+c^2} < \sqrt{b^2+c^2 + 2bc} = b +c$).

Then, separately try for $n<1$ and $1<n\leq2$.

Comment: thanks for hint.i'm thinking about it but still no luck right now.